# How intrusive is tcpdump?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I look around to find a documentation on `tcpdump` internals, but I did not found nothing yet. So my question is how intrusive is `tcpdump` on a computer. How to evaluate the amount of resources (memory or cpu) dedicated for the analysis of the traffic?

Answer (score 4):

tcpdump is very simple tool which is basically opens special type of socket

```
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))
```

and writes to disk everything it gets.

Kernel does all capture and manages special buffer to store packets for tcpdump. If buffer is full packet it just dropped. Buffer is regulated with -B option. Most systems has upper limit for buffer, ~2GB or something like that.

From CPU standpoint you need computation power copy all data 2 or 3 times, this usually is not a problem, if you unable to capture 1GB link you most probable should blame disk speed, not CPU. For 10Gb link it could be CPU problems, and memory bus bandwidth problems, and you may need some optimisations for this.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I read, tcpdump consume it's kinda variable depending what you're asking.

To see how many resources your tcpdump process consumes just watch system monitor like `top` [Top Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top).

> tcpdump output can be considerable if the network traffic your
>   expression defines is high bandwidth; particularly if you are
>   capturing more than the default 68 Bytes of packet content.
>
> Capturing packets, for example, related to a large file transfer or a
>   web server being actively used by hundreds or thousands of clients
>   will produce an overwhelming amount of output. If writing this output
>   to stdout you will probably be unable to enter commands in your
>   terminal, if writing to a file you may exhaust the host’s disk space.
>   In either case tcpdump is also likely to consume a great deal of CPU
>   and memory resources.
>
> To avoid these issues;
>
> - Be very careful when specifying expressions and try to make them as    specific as possible.
> - Don’t capture during times of heavy    traffic/load.
> - If you wish to capture entire packet contents, do a    test capture    only capturing the default 68Bytes first and make a    judgement on
>     whether the system will cope with the full packet    content capture.
> - Where writing to disk, carefully monitor the size of    the file and    make sure the host in question has the likely disk    resources
>     required available, or use the -c parameter to limit the    number of 
>     packets captured.
> - Never use an expression that would    capture traffic to or from your    remote telnet/SSH/whatever    terminal/shell. tcpdump output
>     would    generate traffic to your    terminal, resulting in further
>     output,    resulting in more traffic to    your terminal and so on in
>     an    infinite and potentially harmful    feedback loop.

Origin : [Tcpdump - Basics](http://packetpushers.net/masterclass-tcpdump-basics/)